# OpenSSL Generating RSA key and CA

Tags: openssl, certificate

How could I generate my own RSA private key and Certification Authority. I want to set up a certificate for my corporation's website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating self-signed certificate will cause browser errors for users. Ordinary client visiting your page will close it, when shown the error that certificate is not safe.

The best choice for you is to buy a certificate from trusted CA.

If you still want to create it yourself here are commands:

```
genrsa -des3 -out ca/ca.key 4096
```

To generate RSA private key.

```
req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key ca/ca.key -out ca/ca.cer
```

To create self-signed certificate CA

```
genrsa -des3 -out key.key 4096
```

To create RSA private key for web certificate

```
req -new -key key.key -out cerreq.csr
```

To create CSR

```
ca -policy policy_anything -cert ca/ca.cer -in cerreq.csr -keyfile ca/ca.key -days 365 -out cer.cer
```

To sign certificate with your CA